# iOS UIATarget detect when UIViewController is loaded after a tap()?

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation

I am writing automation testing for my iOS app and I am trying to figure out how to detect in the javascript script when a view controller fully loaded and is on screen...

So right now for example the script taps on a button:

```
target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().buttons()["loginButton"].tap();
```

Then, once the app logs in (which could take a few seconds or less) I need to press another button.

Right now, I made it work by simply putting a delay:

```
target.delay(3);
```

But I want to be able to detect when the next view controller is loaded so that I know I can access the elements on the new screen just loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to achieve that:

1. Tune Up Library

   https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js

   I would really recommend to check this out. They have some useful wrapper function to write  more advanced test. Some methods is written to extend the `UIAElement` class. They have `waitUntilVisible()` method.

   But there might be possibility that the element itself is nil. Its not the matter of visibility but its just not in the screen yet.
2. `UIATargetInstance.pushTimeout(delay)` and `UIATargetInstance.popTimeout()`

   Apple documentation says :

   > To provide some flexibility in such cases and to give you finer
   >   control over timing, UI Automation provides for a timeout period, a
   >   period during which it will repeatedly attempt to perform the
   >   specified action before failing. If the action completes during the
   >   timeout period, that line of code returns, and your script can
   >   proceed. If the action doesn’t complete during the timeout period, an
   >   exception is thrown. The default timeout period is five seconds, but
   >   your script can change that at any time.

   You can also use `UIATarget.delay(delay);` function, but this delays the execution of the next statement, not nescessarily waiting to find the element. `setTimeout(delay)` can also be used to globally set the timeout before UIAutomation decides it could not find the element.

   There is Apple's guide explaining more understanding towards the framework here. http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html

Answer (score 1):

In most cases simply identifying an element specific to the next view controller should be sufficient.  The description of the element must be something unique to the new UI however.

i.e.
`target.frontmostApp().mainWindo().navigationBar()["My Next View"];`

The script should delay until the element can be identified or the timeout has been reached (see `pushTimeout` `popTimout`).

In some cases it might be necessary to specify that the element is visible.

`.withValueForKey(1, "isVisible")`

It's also possible to use `waitForInvalid` to do the reverse (wait for something in the previous UI to go away).

Answer (score 0):

Search for tuneup library [here](https://github.com/alexvollmer/tuneup_js/blob/master/uiautomation-ext.js)

Refer function waitUntilVisible for the same. you may include other files to for supporting functions in it.
Hope it help.

Comment: I can't get tuneup js functions to work properly, for example: mainWindow.waitUntilFoundByName("foo", 100) never find my controller that has accessibilityLabel set to foo. Any ideas?